# selecting small amounts from json output in python

Tags: python, json, bots, telegram, chatbot

this is my current code

```
def info_coin(bot, update, args):
    if args[-1] == '1':
        coin_list = args[:-1]
        opt = 1
    else:
        coin_list = args
        opt = 0
    for coin_name in coin_list:
        coin_call =requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/" + str(coin_name)).json()
        coin_isd = coin_call ['description']['en']
        print(coin_isd)
        update.message.reply_text(coin_isd)
```

i would like to further select `['en']` to only take a select an amount of text from it. Reason being is my message is to long to send.

Comment: your question is unclear. could you expand?

Answer (score 0):

If `coinCall['description']['en']` is a string you can slice it.

Let's say you want to limit the string to 10 characters, you could update your code to the following

```
def infoCoin(bot,update,args,max_string=10):
    if args[-1] == '1':
        coin_list=args[:-1]
        opt=1
    else:
        coin_list=args
        opt=0
    for coinName in coin_list:
        coinCall =requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/"+str(coinName)).json()
        coinIsd = coinCall ['description']['en'][:max_string]
        print(coinIsd)
        update.message.reply_text(coinIsd)
```

Note that if the length of the string is smaller than `max_string`, you will simply get the entire string

```
In [873]: x='string'

In [874]: x[:10]
Out[874]: 'string'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable to the function and make decide how many characters you need to extract from the dictionary. Like in the below example I'm passing 100 so only first 100 characters would be extracted.
Try this code:

```
import requests


def infoCoin(args, total_string_length_to_send):
        coinCall =requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/"+args).json()
        print(coinCall['description']['en'][:total_string_length_to_send])

infoCoin('bitcoin', 100)
```

Comment: what would i do if the  *infoCoin* var gets declared by my user and i want to make sure that only the first 100 char of the api response would be sent to them?

Comment: you can hard code it to 100. `coinCall['description']['en'][:100]`